# How to get a list of mutual friends

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hi IM trying to find out how i can get mutual friends

im currently having problems thinking this out.

I have a table called "users" and this is how it looks

```
id | name
-----------
1   Kenny
2   Jack
3   Jimmy
4   Chris
5   Meg
6   Jake
7   Micheal
8   Dude
```

I have a table called "friendship"
and this is how it looks

```
user_a | user_b 
----------------
4         1        
7         5
8         1
2         4
2         1
5         2
1         6
1         7
```

user_a sends user_b a request to become friends and... BAM there are friends.
Now if im user 2, and i go to user 1s friend list, i want to see what friends we have in common. What is the correct sql to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that it is not possible for User 1 to be friends with User 7 twice, (meaning there can not be a row with `user_a = 1, user_b=7` and another row `user_a = 7, user_b = 1`).

```
SELECT IF(user_a = 1 OR user_a = 2, user_b, user_a) friend
FROM friendship
WHERE (user_a = 1 OR user_a = 2) OR (user_b = 1 OR user_b = 2)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: That's an interesting point (Assuming that it is not possible for User 1 to be friends with User 7 twice) - I doubt that you can actually enforce that restriction in the backend. The best that could be done is probably to make user_a and user_b a composite unique key. Since this is a related question, it'd be great if somebody could suggest a better solution if it's available.

Comment: @user183037 I built a project like this before, and what i did was to create a Primary key on `user_a, user_b`, and insert 2 rows (both combination) for a friend relation. that way its easy to search for a users friends (just search where `user_a=@user`) and do not need a second index on `user_b` alone.