# How to count mutual friends between two users and list them in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know I am not asking a new question but the problem is that I am not getting the things right... Please help me...

I have the following tables:

```
users(user_id, full_name, course etc.)

friends(user_id (sender), friend_id (receiver), status)
```

status decides the relationship, if status=1 it means the request is pending while status=2 means the sender and receiver are friends).

I just want to count the MUTUAL friends between the current logged-in user and the other user (whom the current logged-in user visits the profile).

And also, I want to list them separately.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911156/how-to-get-a-list-of-mutual-friends) answer your question?

Comment: Hi! _thanks_ for replying, I have tried this code, I am not getting exact mutual :( and mutual friends list too...

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Or are you just fishing?

Comment: I have attempted all the queries which I FOUND on STACKOVERFLOW and believe me none of them are working for me...

Comment: What kind of queries are you using ? mysqli, PDO, prepared statements .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
( /*    Dervived table for friends of userid 1 */
SELECT * FROM friends where user_id=1) fsof1
JOIN 
( /*    Dervived table for friends of userid 2 */
SELECT * FROM friends where user_id=2) fsof2
ON fsof1.friend_id = fsof2.friend_id
```